# Missing Microsoft Excel as option in SQL Server data import tool

Tags: sql-server-2012, 64-bit, excel-2007, import-from-excel, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running SQL Server 2012 on a 64bit Windows Server 2012 R2.
I don't have MS Office installed.
I now notice that when I start Start->Program Files->Microsoft SQL Server 2012->Import and Export Data (64-bit) the MS Excel file option is missing from the datasource dropdown. How can I get that option without having to install Excel or Office on my server?

Comment: There is no 64-bit Excel driver for this, IIRC. You need to run the 32-bit Import & Export Wizard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had to install this driver: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255

After that it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Microsoft Excel. It worked for me.