# synchronization between excel and sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to dump my excel data into sql database

I want to  made synchronization between SQL and Excel

Can anybody help me on this

Thanks

Rohan

Comment: Hi, Julien I have stuck in this i have tried everything but not able to connect a link between SQL and Excel so that if we add some data in excel it automatically update in database by itself

Comment: Is this a one off exercise or a regular event? What version of SQL Server are you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (here is a good guide to [import](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/) and [export](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/202/simple-way-to-export-data-from-sql-server/) data). After import/export procedure you can save SSIS package based on what you just did and then use it in job to run it by schedule (good guide [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/23/sql-server-running-ssis-package-in-scheduled-job/)).

**EDIT**

Also you can use linked server for this. Please, read [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2018/using-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-query-excel-files/) article.

One more way is to create macros that will update data on SQL Server side after changing the excel file.

But all options has one ultimate flaw: **they can not provide online update in both sources.** Only on demand (macros, job, SSIS package etc.)

Comment: Hi, I have treid import and export data option but I can't see the Excel in import option in SQL and please tell me how to add screen shot on stackoverflow

Comment: Try this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359446/missing-microsoft-excel-as-option-in-sql-server-data-import-tool . In other words - you need to find and install Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable for your system.

Comment: Note: this must be installed on machine o which SQL Server is running.

Comment: I have downloaded this engine but nothing gets change

Comment: can Task scheduler do this job

Comment: Yes it can, but it is a bit weird to done this via task scheduler and require some tuning. I assume you have no MS Office packages installed on the machine where SQL Server is running?

Comment: yes I have MS office Excel on my machine

Comment: And SQL server is on same machine?

Comment: yes both are on same machine

Comment: Well if you run all on same machine what is version of SQL Server and Office? 64bit or 32bit? And you start wizard this way *Right click on the MSSQLTipsSSISTutorial database in the Object Explorer, select Tasks, then Import Data from the context menu to launch the Import Wizard.* or else way?

Comment: I have windows 10 32bit .  I can't find the version of sql and excel

Comment: If windows is 32bit then everything is 32bit. In SQL Server execute query `SELECT @@VERSION`.

Comment: 11.0.2100.60 this is the version which I found by configure manager option

Comment: I just remembered that I run SQL server on win 10 machine 32bit at home. I'll check if issue occurs on my machine too.

Comment: ok thnks for ur concern buddy I really appreciate that

Comment: You are welcome! I am curious why all is installed and Excel isn't in import option in SQL. Never encounter this in my experience. Ahhh.. just seen your question about screenshots: press Edit near your question. Then put cursor where you want to add image and press Ctrl+G or button with small pic in top menu. Than just enter link to your image or Drug&Drop it on opened form.

Comment: ok I will upload my screen shot   should I download latest version of excel

Comment: buddy u understand my point na tables are import to sql from excel successfully but I want to create a link between excel and sql so that whenever I made any change in my excel the database automatically should updated

Comment: Check updated answer. Please.

Comment: yes I checked that u thinking about importing . tables are import in sql successfully but I want to do it automatic .everytime I should not import those tables from excel there has to be a way to connect a link between excel and sql so that database is update automatically

Comment: Options are: update by schedule, write macros that will update data on SQL side from excel after button press or after column change. I suggest first option.

Comment: I check it, all is on it's places (Windows 10 32bit SQL Server Express 2014 Office 2016). Did you scrolled up when chose data source?

Comment: Hi Buddy ,I got solution for this there is a tool called EXCEL SPREADS which is used to import data from excel to sql and vice versa ..But this tool is not free we have to purchase